# Is it allowed for a Chrome Extension to read page script content via Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently creating a Chrome Extension. But Google officially disallow the extension to access variables or functions defined in the web page:

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> ```
> Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts
> ```

UPDATE:

In the page there are many script tags like:

```
 <script>...<script>
 <script>...<script>
 <script>...<script> 
 <script>
 $config = {};
 $config.a = 1;
 $config.b = 5; 
 function getConfig() {  ...
   // some code  return config; 
 }
 </script> 
 <script>...<script>
 <script>...<script>
```

Is there any way that I can read $config and the function getConfig() from Content Script? Or this is just impossible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you probably noticed chrome.* API can only be used by the background page or other plugin specific pages. Content Scripts on the other hand can access the page but can't use the chrome.* APIs.

What you need to do is use the Content Extension to access whatever you want on the page, and then send a message with the data back to the background page. The background page can then use the data and the chrome.* APIs.

The docs have pretty good examples and documentation around Message Passing between content scripts and the background page.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

## UPDATE

You can only send messages that contain JSON objects. In other words you can't send the getConfig function. But you can send the $config in your example. If the $config object is not JSON you need to serialize it somehow.

*code on the page you can't control*

```
$config = {};
$config.a = 1;
$config.b = 5;
```

*contentscript.js*

```
function getConfig(){return $config;}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({type: 'config', content: getConfig()}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
});
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.type == "config") {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH request.config here
        sendResponse({status: "OK"});
    }
    sendResponse({status: "Unknown request type"});
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, what I need is just to read page variable and functions. I now know how to communicate with Content Script with Background page. But I don't know what I can do with the intro you provided :(

Comment: They only solution currently is to transfer document.scripts and analyzing the strings. but it's too tough and unstable if the page changed something.

Comment: So maybe you should have included a concrete example on your question @AwQiruiGuo

Comment: Thanks very much for the update, I am afraid you misunderstood me. The "$config" variable is not defined by me in the contentscript, but defined in the page (the page is not controlled by me). I actually want to access the variables in a page (just like I can access the DOM nodes).

Comment: No problem. content scripts run on the page. You can use it to get data on the window namespace or to query DOM nodes. I updated my example to reflect that.